# how to send a list generated from text to a client via server

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I curated a list from a raw text file and want to send to client via socket module in python 3 but so far i keep getting an error that it only allows string/byte transfer

```
customer = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode("UTF-8")
            with open('data.txt') as f:
                data = [line.strip().split('|') for line in f]
            for line in data:
                if line[0] == customer:
                    clientsocket.send(data)
                    count = count + 1
            if (count == 0):
                    clientsocket.send(bytes("Customer Not Found!!!", "UTF-8"))
```

Comment: Please show us the full traceback, and example of data and fix your indentation

Comment: thanks gogaz but my problem got solved :)